# Get Jackson XMLMapper to read root element name

Tags: jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

How do I get Jackson's XMLMapper to read the name of the root xml element when deserializing?

I am deserializing input XML to generic Java class, LinkedHashMap and then to JSON. I want to dynamically read the root element of input XML on deserialization to LinkedHashMap.

**Code**

```java
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
Map entries = xmlMapper.readValue(new File("source.xml"), LinkedHashMap.class);
ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = jsonMapper.writer().writeValueAsString(entries);
System.out.println(json);
```

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<File>
  <NumLeases>1</NumLeases>
  <NEDOCO>18738</NEDOCO>
  <NWUNIT>0004</NWUNIT>
  <FLAG>SUCCESS</FLAG>
  <MESSAGE>Test Upload</MESSAGE>
  <Lease>
     <LeaseVersion>1</LeaseVersion>
     <F1501B>
        <NEDOCO>18738</NEDOCO>
        <NWUNIT>0004</NWUNIT>
        <NTRUSTRECORDKEY>12</NTRUSTRECORDKEY>
     </F1501B>
  </Lease>
</File>
```

**Actual Output**

```
{"NumLeases":"1","NEDOCO":"18738","NWUNIT":"0004","FLAG":"SUCCESS","MESSAGE":"Test Upload","Lease":{"LeaseVersion":"1","F1501B":{"NEDOCO":"18738","NWUNIT":"0004","NTRUSTRECORDKEY":"12"}}}
```

**Expected Output** (Note: There is a root element named "File" present in JSON)

```
{"File":{"NumLeases":"1","NEDOCO":"18738","NWUNIT":"0004","FLAG":"SUCCESS","MESSAGE":"Test Upload","Lease":{"LeaseVersion":"1","F1501B":{"NEDOCO":"18738","NWUNIT":"0004","NTRUSTRECORDKEY":"12"}}}}
```

There's probably some switch somewhere to set it. Any help shall be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly there is no flag for that. It can be done with a custom implementation of `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer`. ([Jackson How-To: Custom Deserializers](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers)):

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.deser.FromXmlParser;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
//...
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.registerModule(new SimpleModule().addDeserializer(JsonNode.class, 

    new JsonNodeDeserializer() {

        @Override
        public JsonNode deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
            String rootName = ((FromXmlParser)p).getStaxReader().getLocalName();
            return ctxt.getNodeFactory()
                    .objectNode().set(rootName, super.deserialize(p, ctxt));
        }
    }));

JsonNode entries = xmlMapper.readTree(new File("source.xml"));
System.out.println(entries);
```

Comment: Though my original question was to convert XML to Map but your answer was helpful in providing insight to what I need. The code works perfectly for XML to JSON converter.

Comment: I ended up converting my XML to JSON, so I have edited my question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Kind of annoying that this isn't the default behavior.

Comment: For anyone trying this on 2.13.2 - don't bother, it doesn't work. The `getLocalName()` call will just return the name of the first child XML tag, not the actual root. So in the OP's case that would be *"<NumLeases>"* instead of *"<File>"*. I have not found a solution to this yet.

Answer (score 3):

While this Question has an accepted answer, I found that it doesn't work on the latest Jackson version 2.13.2 and uses flawed approach anyway.

```java
new SimpleModule().addDeserializer(JsonNode.class, 
    new JsonNodeDeserializer() {
        @Override
        public JsonNode deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
            String rootName = ((FromXmlParser)p).getStaxReader().getLocalName();
            return ctxt.getNodeFactory()
                    .objectNode().set(rootName, super.deserialize(p, ctxt));
        }
    }));
```

The `.getLocalName()` call will return the name of the first **child** element, not the actual root of the parsed input. Also, fetching just the *name* of the element ignores the attributes, so you'll end up with just a duplicated tag name in your output.

## What to do instead?

After trying a number of workarounds, I've found only one that works properly. You have to let Jackson do its root node removal and fool it with a dummy wrapper tag.

```java
JsonNode jsonNode = XML_MAPPER.readTree("<tag>" + nestedXmlString + "</tag>");
```

This will wrap the XML with a dummy `<tag>` which is then immediately removed and forgotten.

Then, you can work with the output tree as usual:

```java
toXmlGenerator.writeTree(jsonNode);
```

## Caution

However, please be aware that if your XML input String contains the XML Header declaration (`<?xml...`), then wrapping it with a dummy tag will result in a parsing exception. To avoid this, you'll have to first remove the declaration string from the input:

```java
String nestedXmlString = input;
if (nestedXmlString.startsWith("<?xml")) {
    nestedXmlString = nestedXmlString.substring(nestedXmlString.indexOf("?>") + 2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer works for Jackson 2.10.* (and older probably), but not for any of the newer versions (might get fixed in 2.14 - [source](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/484)).

What worked for me:

```java
public class CustomJsonNodeDeserializer extends JsonNodeDeserializer {
        
    @Override
    public JsonNode deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        //first deserialize
        JsonNode rootNode = super.deserialize(p, context);
        //then get the root name
        String rootName = ((FromXmlParser)p).getStaxReader().getLocalName();
        return context.getNodeFactory().objectNode().set(rootName, rootNode);
    }
}
```

I will update my answer if there's a new better solution.

Comment: Thanks - it does work (as of Jackson 2.13.0)