# Jackson dataformat XmlMapper : how to include parent note while deserialising

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I was able to include parent note with below code . Is there a any simpler way to get this working ? Like setting some properties on XMLMapper?

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    xmlMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    xmlMapper.registerModule(new SimpleModule().addDeserializer(JsonNode.class,
            new JsonNodeDeserializer() {
                @Override
                public JsonNode deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
                    String rootName = ((FromXmlParser)p).getStaxReader().getLocalName();
                    return ctxt.getNodeFactory()
                            .objectNode().set(rootName, super.deserialize(p, ctxt));
                }
            }));
    JsonNode jsonNode = xmlMapper.readTree(xml);
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I understand that well. Can you add an example of json and classes? I guess you could have meant `@ JsonManagedReference` and` @ JsonBackReference` or `@ JsonIdentityInfo`

Comment: You probably already found [Get Jackson XMLMapper to read root element name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36317162/get-jackson-xmlmapper-to-read-root-element-name). It looks like that nothing changed since then. It looks like standard `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer` is used here and you can not change it by any feature. Above solution is acceptable.

Comment: @MichałZiober yes following the same .